# can't display elements which has been added after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got page,which will display our products,so it will load some images and data and it will be big if I load it at one time,so I decide to do it by Ajax and do it by jQuery,here is my code:

```
var static = 1;
$('.carousel-next').live('click',function(){
$(this).attr("disabled", false);
var pos_eq = static++;
var url = 'ajax/ajax.php?count=' + pos_eq;
if ($('.myList').children('li').length <= pos_eq) 
{
$.getJSON(url,function(data){
  if (data[0] != 404)
  {
$('.myList').append(data[0]);
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".stagger").css({"left":"1200px"});
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".imac").css({"left":"1200px"});
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".stagger").animate({"left":"65px","effect":"slide"},500);
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".imac").animate({"left":"350px","effect":"slide"},700); 
  }
});
}
else
{
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".stagger").css({"left":"1200px"});
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".imac").css({"left":"1200px"});
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".stagger").animate({"left":"65px","effect":"slide"},500);
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".imac").animate({"left":"350px","effect":"slide"},700); 
}
});

$('.carousel-previous').live('click',function(){
$(this).attr("disabled", false);
var pos_eq2 = static--;
if (pos_eq2 < 0)
 pos_eq2 = 0;
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq2).children(".stagger").css({"left":"-1200px"});
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq2).children(".imac").css({"left":"-1200px"});      $('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq2).children(".stagger").animate({"left":"65px","effect":"slide"},500);  $('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq2).children(".imac").animate({"left":"350px","effect":"slide"},700);
});
```

when I use it,it will get data from ajax.php page and add it to page(I saw a source code after doing it) but it will now show them,following part should show the elements after adding to page,but it can't.

```
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".stagger").css({"left":"1200px"});
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".imac").css({"left":"1200px"});
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".stagger").animate({"left":"65px","effect":"slide"},500);
$('.myList').children('li').eq(pos_eq).children(".imac").animate({"left":"350px","effect":"slide"},700);
```

where is the problem?

Comment: Do a `console.log( data[0] )` and first make sure you're getting the desired output back.

Comment: I use alert(data[0]) for check,and it will get data.

Answer (score 0):

Append() needs a Dom element, a HTML string or a Jquery Object to work.
So maybe the problem is with your data. Could you show us what output do you get from console.log(data) ?